# How to keep your MVC controllers DRY for Edit->Save->ValidateFail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a Manage User event that takes an an optional userID and displays a user edit screen. There is a manageUserViewModel to go with this screen.

My Manage page has some dependencies - eg, PageTitle, what method to submit to, etc.

If I validate-fail, I need to show the manage screen again, but this time, using the view-model that was passed into the same method.

Supplying these dependencies in the fail scenario isn't very DRY.

How do I step repeating the dependencies?  I tried putting them into a separate method, but that does not feel right.

```
public ActionResult Manage(Guid? UserID)
    {
        User user = this._UserLogic.GetUser(UserID);

        ViewBag.Title = "User List";
        ViewBag.OnSubmit = "Save";
        ManageUserViewModel uvm = Mapper.Map<User, ManageUserViewModel>(user);

        return View("Manage", uvm);
    }


    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult Save(ManageUserViewModel uvm)
    {
        User user = this._UserLogic.GetUser(uvm.UserID);


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

            // This is not very DRY!!!
            ViewBag.Title = "Manage User";
            ViewBag.OnSubmit = "Save";
            return View("Manage", uvm);
        }

        Mapper.Map<ManageUserViewModel, User>(uvm, user );

        this._UserLogic.SaveUser(user);

        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { UserID = user.ID });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand DRY.  DRY does not mean "NEVER repeat yourself", it means that you should not repeat yourself when it makes sense not to.

Different views have different requirements, and creating a complex structure just to avoid repeating yourself violates other best practices, like KISS, and SRP.

SOLID is interesting because Single Responsibility Principle is often at odds with Don't Repeat Yourself, and you have to come up with a balance.  In most cases, DRY loses because SRP is far more important.

It looks to me like you have code here that is handling multiple responsibilities just so you can avoid writing similar code more than once.  I disagree with doing that, because each view has different responsibilities and different requirements.

I would suggest just creating separate controller actions, views, and models for each action, particularly if the validation requirements are different for them.  There may be a few things you can do (like using Partial Views or Editor Templates) to reduce repetition, but in general don't add lots of complexity just to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the 'Manager User' Title and 'Save' OnSubmit strings as properties of on the ManageUserViewModel. This means that you would not have to add them to the ViewBag each time you called Save.

You could also make a ManageUserService which could be responsible for the AutoMapper mappings and saving the user.

You code would then look like this:

```
public ActionResult Manage(Guid? UserID)
{
    var uvm = _userService.GetById(UserId);

    return View("Manage", uvm);
}


[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Save(ManageUserViewModel uvm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Save", uvm);
    }

    _userService.Save(uvm);

    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { UserID = uvm.ID });

}
```

Just put the CRUD logic and AutoMapping functionality in the a class called UserService, and instance of which can be injected using Inversion of Control into your controller.

If you don't want to hard-code your string values into the view model itself, then you could add the values to an ApplicationResources file and reference those from the view model.

Comment: Consider this sequence: Manage  (user enters some values that fail validation) -> Save  -> Manage.  Under your proposal, won't the data that was in the viewModel disappear? IE, the user will get an empty view model back?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find some way to preserve this information between requests, which either means passing it back and forth between the client and server or saving it on the server.  Saving it on the server means something like session but this feels a little heavy to me.  You could add it to your ViewModel as @Ryan Spears suggested.  To me that feels a little wrong, polluting the ViewModel with something that might be considered metadata.  But that is just an opinion and I am not discrediting his answer because it is valid.  Another possibility would be to just add the extra fields to the parameter list of the action method itself and use hidden fields.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Save(ManageUserViewModel uvm, string title, string onSubmit)
{
    ...
}
```

In the form add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="@ViewBag.Title" />
<input type="hidden" name="onSubmit" value="@ViewBag.OnSubmit" />
```

This is essentially the same concept and solution as adding them to the ViewModel except in this situation they are not actually part of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectToAction()` and then export and import your tempdata (to maintain the ModelState) if you're worried about the 3 lines.

Personally I'd find it a lot more readable if you kept the logic in the POST version of the method, as you're performing something slightly different from the GET method, therefore not really repeating yourself. You could you probably keep the two `ViewBag` variables you have inside the View, and then there's no repetition at all.

As a side note: `[HttpPost]` now supersedes `[AcceptVerbs]`

Answer (score 0):

We have come up with another solution that I thought I would share.

This based on the view-model containing info on what actions it can do, but we feel the controller should be specifying these (ie, controlling what actions different links route to)  these because we have cases where the view-models are reused across actions. EG, the case where when you edit you can edit a template or an instance of something - the UI is the same, the only difference is the actions you post to/cancel from.

We abstracted away the part of the view-model that contains the data bound properties and the view model that contains other things we need for the view to render.  We call the property-only object a DTO - it's not a true dto because it contains validation attributes.

We figure that we might be able to re-use these DTO's in the future for ajax or even XML requests - it, can keep validation DRY.

Anyway - here is an example of the code, we are happy with it (for now) and hope it helps others.

```
 [HttpGet]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public virtual ActionResult ManageUser(ManageUserDTO dto, bool PopulateFromObject = true)
    {
        User user = this._UserLogic.GetUser(dto.UserID);

        if (PopulateFromObject)
            Mapper.Map<User, ManageUserDTO>(user, dto);

        ManageUserViewModel vm = new ManageUserViewModel()
        {
            DTO = dto,
            PageTitle = Captions.GetCaption("pageTitle_EditUser"),
            OnSubmit = GetSubmitEventData(this.ControllerName, "SaveUser"),
            OnCancel = GetCancelEventData(this.ControllerName, "ListUsers"),
        };

        return View("ManageUser", vm); 
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult SaveUser(ManageUserViewModel vm)
    {
        User user = this._UserLogic.GetUser(vm.DTO.UserID);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return ManageUser(vm.DTO, false);
        }

        Mapper.Map<ManageUserDTO, User>(vm.DTO, user);

        this._UserLogic.SaveUser(user);

        TempData.AddSuccess(Captions.GetCaption("message_UserSavedSuccessfuly"));
        return RedirectToAction("ManageUser", new { UserID = user.ID });
    }
```

The model-binder will set any URI variables into the dto in the get action.  My logic layer will return a new User object if a call to getUserByID(null) is made.

Comment: BTW - getSubmitEventData returns a POCO that contains an action, controller and label - we render these in the UI.

Comment: See my answer.  It was much too complex to add as a comment, to this.. but it's really a comment to your answer here.